# Can I "flatten" a column with empty cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe below with multiple columns and rows in which the last column only has data for some of the rows. How can I take that last column and write it to a new dataframe while removing the empty cells that would remain if I just copied the entire column?

```
Part Number    Count      Miles
2345125        14         543
5432545        12
6543654        6          112
6754356        22
5643545        6
7657656        8          23
7654567        11         231
3455434        34         112
```

The data frame I want to obtain would be below

```
Miles
543
112
23
231
112
```

I've tried converting the empty cells to NaN and then removing, but I always either get a key error or fail to remove the rows I want. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
# copy the column 
series = df['Miles']

# drop nan values
series = series.dropna()

# one-liner 
series = df['Miles'].dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
df.loc[df.Miles.notna(), 'Miles']
```

Or if you want to drop the rows:

```
df = df[df.Miles.notna()]
```